# Sorting directories by size

Tags: unix, ssh

I'm looking to return a listing of all directories from the server root ordered by size largest to smallest.

Additionally is there a way to just list what folder is taking up the most space on it's own?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do all of it.... I think.

```
du -H / | sort -n -r > bla.txt && head -1 bla.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain the command in more detail please?

Comment: What is there to explain? Just `man` over it. `du` does the listing, `-H` sets the size format, `|` is a pipe operator, `sort` sorts the piped data `-n` numerically and `-r` reverses it. When it's done `>` redirects stdout to `bla.txt` file. `&&` will append another command that gets executed and that's `head` which will read `-1` first line from `bla.txt`, which is the largest folder under `/`.

Comment: Awesome. I get it. Thanks alot.